# What method is used to calculate confidence intervals in R's MASS package function confint.glm?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model

***What method is used to calculate confidence intervals in R's `MASS` package function `confint.glm`?***

The [helpfile](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/confint.html) states that:

> These `confint` methods call the appropriate profile method, then find
>   the confidence intervals by interpolation in the profile traces.

Can anyone point me in the direction of some literature that could help me to understand what this means?

Comment: See [this previous answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9833/constructing-95-confidence-interval-based-on-profile-likelihood).

Comment: @Cyan Thanks. Is it adequate to say in a manuscript that "confidence intervals were estimated using the profile likelihood method (Venables & Ripley, 2002)" ? If so, add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I also provided some references in [this response](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/5320/930). I think you can find additional references by looking at the [ProfileLikelihood](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ProfileLikelihood/) package, or this [on-line course](http://www.unc.edu/courses/2010fall/ecol/563/001/docs/lectures/lecture8.htm#profileci).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To summarise the above comments for posterity, the confidence interval is known as the "profile likelihood confidence interval".

An explanation of the method is given by [Stryhn and Christensen](http://people.upei.ca/hstryhn/stryhn208.pdf), and in Venables and Ripley's MASS book, §8.4, pp. 220-221.

It has weaker assumptions that the better known Wald method, but requires more computation.

Answer (score 2):

See this document for a pretty good explanation of how profile confidence intervals are determined: http://www.math.umt.edu/patterson/ProfileLikelihoodCI.pdf