# How is the confidence interval for variance component in "lmer" function computed by the command "confint"?

Tags: r, self-study, anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Here is the R code :

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
confint(fm1)

Computing profile confidence intervals ...
                 2.5 %     97.5 %
.sig01       14.3815760  37.715996
.sig02       -0.4815007   0.684986
.sig03        3.8011641   8.753383
.sigma       22.8982669  28.857997
(Intercept) 237.6806955 265.129515
Days          7.3586533  13.575919
```

I understand how  the confidence interval for `(Intercept)` and `coefficient of Days` are calculated (though it is **not profile** confidence intervals ) :

```
res=summary(fm1)
ans=coefficients(res)
estimate = ans[,1]
se = ans[,2]

ci.int = estimate[1]+qnorm(c(.025,.975))*se[1]
[1] 238.0292 264.7810

 ci.day = estimate[2]+qnorm(c(.025,.975))*se[2]
 [1]  7.437595 13.496977
```

But I don't know how are the confidence interval of `sig01` , `sig02` , `sig03` , `sigma` calculated ?

Comment: For the variance components, those are profile likelihood CIs. An explanation of how such CIs are constructed is given here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/9833/1934

Comment: I am trying to calculate the confidence interval (whether it is profiled or not) of variance component in that manner that I have calculated for `(Intercept)` and `Days` .

Comment: Those are Wald-type CIs. They usually perform terribly for variance components, so that's why the ``confint()`` function doesn't calculate them this way. Profile CIs are obtained via iterative methods - there is no closed-form equation.

Comment: @Wolfgang If I want to calculate the confidence interval of variance component based on asymptotic standard normal distribution (**not profile**) , how can I calculate them ?

Comment: @Wolfgang Could you please give me some reference of "Why does wald type CI give poor estimates for variance component?"